# CakePHP and Apache Load Balancer losing session

Tags: apache, cakephp, load-balancing

I have an app running CakePHP 2.1 in a load balanced environment. It seems to lose the session when the server changes between requests. Does anyone know cake config settings or apache config settings that could help this problem?

Comment: What storage setting are you currently using for sessions? When using 'php', session-data is stored inside a global 'temp' directory on the server, using 'Cake', sessions are stored inside `app/tmp/session`. Is each load-balanced server using the same drive/hard disk to serve the site from?

Comment: I am using php session-data in Cake, the security setting is medium at the moment. They are really just virtual servers so they use the same drive/hard disk.

Comment: How does the load-balancing work, is the use redirected to different ip-addresses? Or via a proxy? Is it possible that the instances don't use the same user-account, therefore aren't able to access the session data? You may try to switch to 'cake' for sessions (which also keeps the session-data inside the app directory, IMO a little more safe). Otherwise, using 'database' to store the session data might be worth trying as this will not cause trouble with different user-accounts.

Comment: Yes there are different ip-addresses. There are no user accounts involved, just losing session data that is written after a form is submitted. It's not losing the session in my dev environment which isn't load balanced. I use a one way rsync to sync the two code bases. I will try cake sessions and see if this makes a difference.

Comment: You may check the request that is sent by the browser, check if the session-cookie is actually sent after switching to a different server, just to narrow-down if the *browser* stops the session, or the *server* isn't accepting the session-id